# Trunk doesn't compile because libprotoc is old when working with Hadoop under Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, hadoop

I am following ["working with Hadoop under Eclipse"](http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/EclipseEnvironment) and trying to run

```
$ mvn install -DskipTests
```

After a while, I received an error:

> [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-maven-plugins:3.0.0-SNAPSHOT:protoc (compile-protoc) on project hadoop-common: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: protoc version is 'libprotoc 2.4.1', expected version is '2.5.0' -> [Help 1]

It is the same as [what is reported in this page](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HADOOP-9882).

Does anyone know how to solve it? How should I do to upgrade libprotoc?

Comment: -1 for not doing the basics.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Protocol Buffers is used as an RPC protocol between different daemons. Some of the Linux releases don't have the required version. So, Protocol Buffers code has to be downloaded from [here](http://code.google.com/p/protobuf/), built and installed. These are the instructions from the README.txt in the downloaded bundle.

```
To build and install the C++ Protocol Buffer runtime and the Protocol Buffer compiler (protoc) execute the following:

$ ./configure
$ make
$ make check
$ make install

If "make check" fails, you can still install, but it is likely that some features of this library will not work correctly on your system. Proceed at your own risk. "make install" may require superuser privileges.
```

Answer (score 2):

Execute this bash function, which will download protobuffer 2.5.0 and install with `sudo` permission. (Tested in ubuntu 13.04)

```
  configureProtoc(){                                                                                     
          sudo apt-get install -y gcc g++ make maven cmake zlib zlib1g-dev libcurl4-openssl-dev          
          curl -# -O https://protobuf.googlecode.com/files/protobuf-2.5.0.tar.gz                         
          gunzip protobuf-2.5.0.tar.gz                                                                   
          tar -xvf protobuf-2.5.0.tar                                                                    
          cd protobuf-2.5.0                                                                              
          ./configure --prefix=/usr                                                                      
          make                                                                                           
          sudo make install                                                                              
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Dont forget to link shared libraries after installing protoc :

> ldconfig