# Installing Hadoop 2.6.0 on Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: java, maven, ubuntu, hadoop

I downloaded Hadoop 2.6.0 from Apache mirrors and trying to build it from source, using [these instructions](http://www.ercoppa.org/Linux-Compile-Hadoop-220-fix-Unable-to-load-native-hadoop-library.htm#msg). I have Java 1.7 and Maven 3.0.4 installed.

When I started building Hadoop it gave me error saying hadoop-common is unable to download. So I downloaded it from a separate pom then I came across this:

> [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-maven-plugins:2.6.0:protoc (compile-protoc) on project hadoop-common: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: protoc version is 'libprotoc 2.4.1', expected version is '2.5.0' -> [Help 1]

When I searched for help I got the above link mentioned. I am stuck at step where we are trying to configure protobuf when I run the command "./configure..." I get the error

```
 bash: ./configure: No such file or directory
```

Is there a better way to do this?

The maven run failed with following details:

```
[WARNING] [protoc, --version] failed with error code 1
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Reactor Summary:
[INFO] 
[INFO] Apache Hadoop Main ................................ SUCCESS [1.258s]
[INFO] Apache Hadoop Project POM ......................... SUCCESS [0.430s]
[INFO] Apache Hadoop Annotations ......................... SUCCESS [1.802s]
[INFO] Apache Hadoop Project Dist POM .................... SUCCESS [0.446s]
[INFO] Apache Hadoop Assemblies .......................... SUCCESS [0.228s]
[INFO] Apache Hadoop Maven Plugins ....................... SUCCESS [1.479s]
[INFO] Apache Hadoop MiniKDC ............................. SUCCESS [1.115s]
[INFO] Apache Hadoop Auth ................................ SUCCESS [2.244s]
[INFO] Apache Hadoop Auth Examples ....................... SUCCESS [0.896s]
[INFO] Apache Hadoop Common .............................. FAILURE [0.351s]
[INFO] Apache Hadoop NFS ................................. SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Hadoop KMS ................................. SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Hadoop Common Project ...................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Hadoop HDFS ................................ SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Hadoop HttpFS .............................. SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Hadoop HDFS BookKeeper Journal ............. SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Hadoop HDFS-NFS ............................ SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Hadoop HDFS Project ........................ SKIPPED
[INFO] hadoop-yarn ....................................... SKIPPED
[INFO] hadoop-yarn-api ................................... SKIPPED
[INFO] hadoop-yarn-common ................................ SKIPPED
[INFO] hadoop-yarn-server ................................ SKIPPED
[INFO] hadoop-yarn-server-common ......................... SKIPPED
[INFO] hadoop-yarn-server-nodemanager .................... SKIPPED
[INFO] hadoop-yarn-server-web-proxy ...................... SKIPPED
[INFO] hadoop-yarn-server-applicationhistoryservice ...... SKIPPED
[INFO] hadoop-yarn-server-resourcemanager ................ SKIPPED
[INFO] hadoop-yarn-server-tests .......................... SKIPPED
[INFO] hadoop-yarn-client ................................ SKIPPED
[INFO] hadoop-yarn-applications .......................... SKIPPED
[INFO] hadoop-yarn-applications-distributedshell ......... SKIPPED
[INFO] hadoop-yarn-applications-unmanaged-am-launcher .... SKIPPED
[INFO] hadoop-yarn-site .................................. SKIPPED
[INFO] hadoop-yarn-registry .............................. SKIPPED
[INFO] hadoop-yarn-project ............................... SKIPPED
[INFO] hadoop-mapreduce-client ........................... SKIPPED
[INFO] hadoop-mapreduce-client-core ...................... SKIPPED
[INFO] hadoop-mapreduce-client-common .................... SKIPPED
[INFO] hadoop-mapreduce-client-shuffle ................... SKIPPED
[INFO] hadoop-mapreduce-client-app ....................... SKIPPED
[INFO] hadoop-mapreduce-client-hs ........................ SKIPPED
[INFO] hadoop-mapreduce-client-jobclient ................. SKIPPED
[INFO] hadoop-mapreduce-client-hs-plugins ................ SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Hadoop MapReduce Examples .................. SKIPPED
[INFO] hadoop-mapreduce .................................. SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Hadoop MapReduce Streaming ................. SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Hadoop Distributed Copy .................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Hadoop Archives ............................ SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Hadoop Rumen ............................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Hadoop Gridmix ............................. SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Hadoop Data Join ........................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Hadoop Ant Tasks ........................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Hadoop Extras .............................. SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Hadoop Pipes ............................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Hadoop OpenStack support ................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Hadoop Amazon Web Services support ......... SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Hadoop Client .............................. SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Hadoop Mini-Cluster ........................ SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Hadoop Scheduler Load Simulator ............ SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Hadoop Tools Dist .......................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Hadoop Tools ............................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Hadoop Distribution ........................ SKIPPED
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 11.698s
[INFO] Finished at: Fri May 29 14:15:45 IST 2015
[INFO] Final Memory: 49M/342M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-maven-plugins:2.6.0:protoc (compile-protoc) on project hadoop-common: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: protoc version is 'libprotoc 2.4.1', expected version is '2.5.0' -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] After correcting the problems, you can resume the build with the command
[ERROR]   mvn <goals> -rf :hadoop-common
```

Answer: So I have posted the answer for this issue. I don't see the distribution anywhere should I build it using `mvn package -Pdist,native -DskipTests -Dtar`? I don't see anything in the folder mentioned as per [this link](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.6.0/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-common/NativeLibraries.html).

If am trying to run the command mentioned above then I see several issues in Java file.

Comment: make sure you are in the right directory, `configure` should be a file with `execute` right

Comment: thats correct but where is this configure file? Atleast i dont see it in protobuf it has only 2 folders META-INF and com (basically the java source) and i dont see why people are down voting...!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly follow the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19556253/trunk-doesnt-compile-bcoz-libprotoc-is-old-when-working-with-hadoop-under-eclip). I ran the script given by one of the members in that post. Then whenever you encounter a issue saying a timeout exception to download a jar, pre-download the jar from some dummy pom.

thats it..!!!